# express-validator converting body to [object Object]

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to escape form input for a simple demo express app, and I'm getting a result I don't understand.

When I execute this route:

```
/* Update a toy */
app.post('/toys/:id', [
    body().escape()
], (req, res) => {
    console.log("Update: ");
    console.log(req.body);
    toyController.update(req, res);
});
```

I get this output:

```
Update: 
[object Object]
```

It looks to me as if the request body is getting destroyed.

If I remove the middleware,

```
/* Update a toy */
app.post('/toys/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Update: ");
    console.log(req.body);
    toyController.update(req, res);
});
```

I get the expected result:

```
Update: 
{
  toy: {
    name: 'Playstation 4',
    description: 'A gaming console',
    manufacturer: 'Sony',
    price: '400'
  },
  commit: 'Update Toy'
}
```

Update:  If I call `body('toy')` instead of `body()`, I get the following result:

```
{ toy: '[object Object]', commit: 'Update Toy' }
```

So, it appears that the problem lies in the fact that that body is a nested object.

How can I apply the validation/sanitization to `body.toy` instead of all of `body`?

Is there a way that I can directly call the `escape` code an apply it to a specific string, instead of using the entire middleware setup?

Comment: Try: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

Comment: I get this: `"[object Object]"` (this time with quotes).  It looks as of the "objectness" of `body` as been destroyed.

Comment: @Zack "[object Object]" is returned when you call default toString() function on an object. 
When you specify body().espace(), since your body is an object somewhere in the express validator library, it should be calling toString on the input.
escape() function is part of 'validator' library which expects the argument to be always a string.
In order to sanitize, you have pick each one separately as in the answer below.

Comment: You can use `[body('toy.name').escape(), body('toy.description').escape()]` to escape specific fileds in nested object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use body().escape() in a correct way. Please refer below an example.

```
const express = require('express');
const { body } = require('express- 
validator');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/comment', [
  body('email')
    .isEmail()
    .normalizeEmail(),
  body('text')
    .not().isEmpty()
.trim()
.escape(),
  body('notifyOnReply').toBoolean()
], (req, res) => {
 // Handle the request somehow
});
```

Above example contains the right way to use express validator.In the example above, we are validating email and text fields, so we may take advantage of the same chain to apply some sanitization, like e-mail normalization (normalizeEmail) and trimming (trim)/HTML escaping (escape).
The notifyOnReply field isn't validated, but it can still make use of the same check function to convert it to a JavaScript boolean.

Sorry the indentation is not good, I am posting the answer from mobile.

Since you modified the question. You can use schema validation by express- validator.

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html

Comment: Calling `body('toy')` instead of `body` produces this result: `{ toy: '[object Object]', commit: 'Update Toy' }` I think the problem lies in the fact that the data is nested.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Use schema validation, instead of body, because your object contains nested data amd multiple keys.